# In vue js how to call child component method using check box rendered via slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-slots

I have a parent component:

```html
<my-component>
  <template v-slot:myslot>
    <b-form-group
       label="SlotEG"
       label-for="sltLbl"
       label-class="font-weight-bold pt-0"
    >
      <b-form-checkbox
        :id="myId"
        :name="myName"
      ></b-form-checkbox>
    </b-form-group>
  </template>
<my-component>
```

Here in my child component I have method and I need to call that method while clicking on the check box to capture the checkbox event.

```html
<template>
  <b-col cols="3" v-if="hasMySlot()">
    <slot name="myslot"></slot>
  </b-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    myMethod() {
      alert("Hi")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) to pass the method:

```html
<!-- MyComponent -->
<slot name="myslot" :myMethod="myMethod" />
```

Then you could [destructure the slot prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props) for the passed method, and bind it to the checkbox's handler:

```html
<!-- Parent -->
<my-component>
  <template v-slot:myslot="{ myMethod }">
    ...
    <b-form-checkbox @checked="myMethod" />
  </template>
</my-component>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-method-to-slot-children-iwq7r?file=/src/App.vue:47-93)

Comment: I have used the same code as above but my slot is not getting rendered

Comment: Check box is not rendering.

Comment: @Aathira That's likely unrelated to the scoped slot. See the demo link to see this solution in action.

Comment: @ tony19 thanks for the demo. I have figured out the issue   I was using   '@checked' instead of '@change'.

Comment: Using the wrong event name wouldn't prevent rendering. The problem was probably elsewhere.